# Reference class member (was) causing undefined behavior

Tags: c++, class, reference, initialization

I'm attempting to make a class which holds another class as a reference (private member).

```
class example{
private:
    std::vector<char> chars;
};

class example2{
    example2(example to_be_initialized) :ref(to_be_initialized) { }
private:
    example& ref;
};
```

Hopefully the lack of detail won't bug anyone (I know you guys like to see the full code, but I reduced it because if this isn't the problem it's something else I have to figure out. But I will post more/the rest if needed), but I had code very similar to this, and I would get weird unicode characters when doing anything involving ref. once I changed ref to a non-reference, all the weird undefined behavior went away.

I'd like to know if the above is legal simply for future reference. I know in this scenario I'm not saving a whole lot of memory by referencing the class (since it's just copying pointers, right?), but I feel something like this would be necessary in the future.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a major issue with the code: the constructor takes its parameter by value, which means the reference refers to a temporary object. After the constructor call, it is left as a dangling reference.

You need to initialize the reference from a valid object. You can do this by making the constructor parameter a reference:

```
class example2
{
public:
    example2(example& to_be_initialized) : ref(to_be_initialized) { }

private:
    example& ref;
};
```

then

```
example e;
example2 e2(e); // e2.ref and e are the same object
```

Note: You must make sure you understand the semantics of a reference to use this. A reference isn't really "like a pointer". It is an alias for one and only one existing object. Unless you actually *need* referential semantics, you should store an object:

```
class example2
{
public:
    example2(const example& to_be_initialized) : ex(to_be_initialized) { }

private:
    example ex;
};
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't catch that, and that my program sometimes "worked" even with a dangling reference. Unfortunately the reference class does have functions I need to call so I can't make it a constant, but I will definitely keep that in mind in the future because I hadn't ever thought about it that way. Thanks again for the detailed response :) (and hopefully I didn't make any wrong assumptions above)

Comment: @cjh418 I don't think I said anything about making it a constant, whatever "it" is. Nor does that have much to do with calling functions.

Comment: Oh you're right, I misinterpreted your example as changing "ex" (from your final example) to a constant. I see now that you mean for the parameter to be constant unless I need to modify it inside the constructor.

Comment: Actually, your example won't even compile that way (invalid initialization of type ex& from expression of type const ex), I guess that's why I assumed you were talking about changing the private member ex (again, referring to your last example) to a const.

Comment: @cjh418 They both compile, once the constructor has been made public (I foolishly cut and pasted from your broken example assuming it compiled.) See [here](http://ideone.com/pLSwIS) and [here](http://ideone.com/pjI8M5). You are clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: Yeah you're right, it does work. I was changing the private member to a reference (ignored that part of your example), I guess I'm reading too fast. I see what you mean by "storing" now, thanks.